# How to fix or limit MoUsoCoreWorker.exe excessive RAM usage?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, memory-management, memory-leaks

MoUsoCoreWorker.exe has been causing problems since last month (June 2021), unexpectedly causing crashes and system instability due to excessive memory usage... on a computer with 16 GB RAM.

I checked the system event log and found "Resource Exhaustion Detector" indicating MoUsoCoreWorker using nearly 4 GB of RAM. MsMpEng (Windows Defender) also uses a suspiciously high amount of RAM (750 MB) at the same time.

(The computer in question is often running other programs that use 8 GB of RAM total; therefore unusual and excessive background RAM usage will probably cause problems.)

The "page file" on that computer is largely disabled (limited to 16 MB) for good reason - so runaway/poorly programmed background processes don't shred its persistent storage with excessive writes.

I read up on what MoUsoCoreWorker does - it's a Windows Update process. There is no legitimate reason for an update process to use 4 GB of RAM. Maybe 500 MB would be a realistic allocation at most.

I haven't noticed this problem before June 2021, indicating it's either caused by a bad update to MoUsoCoreWorker (probably a memory leak) or poorly structured recent updates that cause unreasonable memory usage.

How do I put a hard limit on MoUsoCoreWorker's memory footprint? I want to force it to either limit memory usage to a reasonable level, or "wait" for other programs to relinquish memory before allocating dangerous amounts of RAM. If that's impossible, I will be forced to disable it by setting its startup configuration to "Manual" or "Disabled", then run it manually to pull updates as needed.

Comment: Disabling Windows update services is an inefficient way to prevent Windows update.  Those services will be started again, more effective to postpone them or set activity hours.

Comment: Same here. 16 GB machine and also running a VM in the background using VMware Workstation 14. Virtual Disk is set to auto, so the MoUsoCoreWorker process grew up to 36.8GB before stuff started to crash. I've been having issues with FireFox and video playback. Starting to make sense now...